# How to reduce quality (filesize) for animated gif with PHP (ImageMagick)?

Tags: php, imagemagick, animated-gif

I want to reduce the quality of an animated GIF to reduce GIF filesize. Animation and dimensions should stay the same.

Is this even possible?

I've tried various Imagemagick functions, but with no luck. Maybe someone has done this?

This is just a logical thinking, but it would be cool, if something like this would work:

````
$gif = new Imagick($tempFilePath);
$gif = $gif->coalesceImages();

foreach ($gif as $frame) {                                  
    $frame->setImageCompression(8);
    $frame->setImageCompressionQuality(10);
}

$gif = $gif->deconstructImages();
$gif->writeImages($tempFilePath, true);```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GIF does not use compression. So your compression arguments will not do anything. In ImageMagick command line, the **simplest** way is just to reduce the number of colors in the animation.

Input (Mount St. Helens colorized):

[image]

```
convert animation.gif -coalesce +dither -colors 64 -layers optimize animation2.gif
```

[image]

I am not an Imagick expert, but I think what you want is [quantizeImages](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.quantizeimages.php), which I believe will reduce colors for an animation or set of images. See also the example at [quantizeImage](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.quantizeimage.php) to reduce the colors of one single image.

Note that I first use -coalesce to fill out the frames. I use +dither to avoid dithering when reducing colors. And finally I re-optimize the animation.

However, the **better way** is to use **one common color map** for all frames and use as few colors as possible. Then also do layer optimization on the animation. This can be done as follows on this simple (extremely small number) 3-color example.

Input (Mount St. Helens colorized):

[image]

3-color Color Table (enlarged for viewing):

```
convert xc:red xc:green1 xc:blue +append colortable.gif
```

[image]

```
convert animation.gif -coalesce +dither -remap colortable.gif -layers optimize new_animation.gif
```

[image]

**More practically**, you can create a reduced color table by collecting all the colors from all the combined animation frames, reduce the colors and then get the unique colors. For example:

```
convert animation.gif -coalesce +append +dither -colors 64 -unique-colors -depth 8 colortable2.gif
```

[image]

Then apply this color table to the animation

```
convert animation.gif -coalesce +dither -remap colortable2.gif -layers optimize new_animation2.gif
```

[image]

The file sizes are:

```
animation.gif ---  481 K
animation2.gif (64 colors) --- 479 K
new_animation (3 colors) --- 57 K
new_animation2 (64 colors) --- 393 K
```

**For Imagick, see the following methods:**

[coalesce](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.coalesceimages.php)

[remap](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.remapimage.php)

[append](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.appendimages.php)

[uniquecolors](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.uniqueimagecolors.php)

[quantizeimage for reduced colors](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.quantizeimage.php)